# changing fields in Array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays

**this is part of the class i created

```
    class Student{ 
 private String name;

 private float avGrade;

 private float outstandingGrade = 82.0f;

public Student() {  }

public Student(String Name, float avg) {
    name = Name;
    avGrade = avg;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String Name) {
    name = Name;
}
```

}

and this is the main and another method in it :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student[][] school = CreateStudentMat();
    school[0][0].setName("Student");
}
public static Student[][] CreateStudentMat(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter number of classes in school: ");
    int NumClasses = input.nextInt();
    Student[][] matrix = new Student[NumClasses][];  
    for(int i = 0; i<matrix.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter number of students in class " +(i+1));
        matrix[i] = new Student[input.nextInt()];
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

when i am trying to change name of the object at [0][0]
with school[0][0].setName("Student");

i get an error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Homework3.main(Homework3.java:13)

what i did wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

- you are instantiating the two dimensional array with `matrix = new Student[NumClasses][]`
- you are instantiating the N one dimensional arrays with `matrix[i] = new Student[input.nextInt()]`
- you are **NOT** instantiating every single student with `matrix[i][j] = new Student()`

Hence the two dimensional array is correctly created but every student reference is still `null` since you are not instantiating any.

Answer (score 0):

There are no student objects. you never called `new Student()` anywhere. Since array does not have any object, you can't call methods on nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem exist at:

```
Student[][] matrix = new Student[NumClasses][];
```

try to initialize the size of the second dimension of your array.